# access denied for user `nobody' from `systemd-user'

Tags: ubuntu

I've been seeing a lot of the following in my xenial auth.log:

```
systemd: pam_succeed_if(systemd-user:account): requirement "uid < 2000" was met by user "root"
systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
runuser: pam_unix(runuser-l:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
runuser: pam_unix(runuser-l:session): session closed for user root
systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session closed for user root
systemd: pam_succeed_if(systemd-user:account): requirement "uid < 2000" not met by user "nobody"
systemd: pam_access(systemd-user:account): access denied for user `nobody' from `systemd-user'
runuser: pam_unix(runuser-l:session): session opened for user nobody by (uid=0)
runuser: pam_unix(runuser-l:session): session closed for user nobody
systemd: pam_succeed_if(systemd-user:account): 'uid' resolves to '65534'
systemd: pam_succeed_if(systemd-user:account): requirement "uid < 2000" not met by user "nobody"
systemd: pam_access(systemd-user:account): access denied for user `nobody' from `systemd-user'
runuser: pam_unix(runuser-l:session): session opened for user nobody by (uid=0)
runuser: pam_unix(runuser-l:session): session closed for user nobody
```

The action being taken is in accordance with /etc/pam.d/common-account:

```
account    [success=1 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]      pam_unix.so
account    requisite            pam_deny.so
account    required            pam_permit.so
account    sufficient                      pam_succeed_if.so uid < 2000
account    required                        pam_access.so
account    [success=ok new_authtok_reqd=done ignore=ignore user_unknown=ignore authinfo_unavail=ignore default=bad]        pam_ldap.so minimum_uid=2000
```

but I cannot figure out what exactly is trying to run as user nobody.
I found the following in syslog:

```
systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of nobody.
systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 65534...
systemd[1]: Started Session c7289 of user nobody.
collectd[15403]: 0 Success: 1 value has been dispatched.
collectd[15403]: message repeated 21 times: [ 0 Success: 1 value has been dispatched.]
systemd[32704]: user@65534.service: Failed at step PAM spawning /lib/systemd/systemd: Operation not permitted
systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 65534.
systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 65534.
systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of nobody.
```

and when I check that user@65534.service, it indeed seems it cannot be started:

```
● user@65534.service - User Manager for UID 65534
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/user@.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)


systemd[31364]: pam_succeed_if(systemd-user:account): requirement "uid < 2000" not met by user "nobody"
systemd[31364]: pam_access(systemd-user:account): access denied for user `nobody' from `systemd-user'
systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 65534.
systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 65534.
systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 65534...
systemd[32704]: pam_succeed_if(systemd-user:account): 'uid' resolves to '65534'
systemd[32704]: pam_succeed_if(systemd-user:account): requirement "uid < 2000" not met by user "nobody"
systemd[32704]: pam_access(systemd-user:account): access denied for user `nobody' from `systemd-user'
systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 65534.
systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 65534.
```

but I cannot figure out exactly what needs this or why it needs to be started every once in a while or by what.

I did a grep for "nobody" and "65534" in /usr/lib/systemd/ and /etc/systemd but came up short. Likewise, I checked /etc/cron but apart from /etc/cron.daily/popularity-contest, which I removed in the meantime, there's nothing that runs as user nobody.

For the life in my I cannot figure out what tries to start this service or for what purpose. I also can't disable the "user@65534.service" because it's static and I'm also not sure it's a good idea.

Btw, the user itself:

```
# getent passwd nobody
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The `auth` log would be where authorization attempts are logged.  Do you have any internet facing services that attempt user authorization?  Most likely someone is attempting to login as that user through your SSH server.

Comment: Originally I thought so too but there is no ssh log indicating as such.

Comment: Do you have any cron jobs that run as this user? Do you have any jobs that **use `su` or `sudo`** to switch to this user? What are the log lines immediately before the PAM messages?

Comment: nothing about "nobody" or "65534" under /etc/cron*, /usr/lib/systemd or /etc/systemd. There used to be the popularity-contest daily cron but I removed it a while back.

Comment: @u1686_grawity I've edited the first code block to include additional logs, immediately before the PAM messages for user "nobody"

Comment: Looks like runuser is being used, so the next thing would be to use `extrace` or `forkstat` (or `execsnoop` for BPF) to see what exactly is running that.